# Como fazer uma página com imagem fullscreen e botões no Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Pessoal preciso criar uma página inicial em Wordpress para um cliente que deve ter somente uma imagem em fullscreen e dois botões para escolha das filiais.
Esta página não pode aparecer header nem footer, apenas a imagem e os dois botões.
Estou usando Divi Builder. Em anexo a imagem para terem uma ideia.[imagem de seleção](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbFrQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

No Divi, nos atributos da página, pode escolher "Blank Page" isso irá tirar o header e o footer e mostrar apenas o conteúdos.

Uma solução menos elegante é tirar os elementos via css na página pretendida.
Pode também construir um modelo de página novo no wordpress: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/